# Find the coordinates of the following vectors relative to the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image]

How would I solve this problem (let's just do $3a$)?

I can find the relative coordinates by putting it in an augmented matrix and putting it in RREF form. Let's just do $3a$ instead of both:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -\frac{2}{7} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{5}{7}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

However, the correct answer for 3a is as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
11\\
-2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

I'm not exactly sure how to get that answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$3(2,-1) + 1(5,1) = x _1 (1,0) + x _2 (0,1)$

Our job at this question is to find $x _1 , x _2$.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOH Ok thank you so much I see!

Comment: More than welcome :)